# Fusion Chart entry with value 0 makes the x axis values to NaNM

Tags: javascript, php, fusioncharts

So I am trying to populate a chart with some entries and when I have one entry with value 0 the values on the x axis are no longer incremented. It's there any way of auto incrementing the x axis if the value is 0?

The chart picture:
[image: chartPic]

My code is:

```
$strXML = "<graph caption='' subCaption='' yaxisname='Nr. documente' xaxisname='Directii' showAlternateVGridColor='1' alternateVGridAlpha='10' alternateVGridColor='AFD8F8' numDivLines='4' decimalPrecision='0' canvasBorderThickness='1' canvasBorderColor='114B78' baseFontColor='114B78' hoverCapBorderColor='114B78' hoverCapBgColor='E7EFF6' formatNumberScale='1' thousandSeparator='.' decimalSeparator=','>";
```

And I populate the chart from my database something like this:

```
$strXML .= "<set name='" . $row["Name"] . "' value='".$row2["Number"]."' color='". getFCColor() ."' />";
```

Then I close the graph and after I render it:

```
$strXML .= "</graph>"; 
echo renderChart("../componente/fusion_bar/swf/FCF_Bar2D.swf", "", $strXML, "productSales", 800,500);
```

Comment: LATER UPDATE: I set the yAxisMinValue='0' and yAxisMaxValue='5'

Comment: seems like the value you are getting is not in correct format, can you please check the value that you are retrieving, because the y-axis is not scaling properly, further I would suggest you to upgrade since flash versions are pretty old, and FusionCharts now use javascript to render charts, here is a demo  - http://jsfiddle.net/x91yqusv/